# How can i keep a stream opened to receive data without closing the socket and waiting for client's data?

Tags: java, sockets

I'm programming in Java and i'm making a socket connection between server and several clients (using threads).
In the client side i made an opened Socket that connects to the server in a respective port and i send several objects, then the client disconnects.
In the server side i made a ServerSocket (where the client connects) and i use the accept() method to get the Socket, i don't want the socket to close so i keep it opened until i want (using a method for example), then i create an stream (ObjectInputStream) and read every object sent from the client, but i don't want it to close too. To continue the understanding of my problem here is the class i made:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ServerConnection implements Runnable{
    private Socket connection;
    
    public ServerConnection(Socket c){
        connection = c;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // I used String i this example, but the real code use a Object sending system that i created
        // because i needed to send different objects in one object (this ones implements Serializable).
        String msg;
        try {
            ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            do{
                inStream.
                msg = ((String)inStream.readObject());
                System.out.println(msg);
            }
            while(!msg.equals("FINISH CONNECTION"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("run() - (io): "+ex.getMessage());
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (IOException ex1) {
                System.err.println("run() - (io/io): "+ex.getMessage());
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.err.println("run() - (classNF): "+ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    // The main method was created to make tests
    // I'll use objects of this class to every client connection
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8010);
            Socket connection = server.accept();
            ServerConnection svConnection = new ServerConnection(connection);
            Thread theThread = new Thread(svConnection);
            theThread .start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This can receive the Strings i sent from the client, but the do-while isn't able to catch exceptions, the IOException is throwed when the Stream has no more Strings, so i want to prevent the throwing of that exception when the stream doesn't have more Strings to read, i tried to use recursive try-catch but i know that is not recommended. So there is another solution to this?
(Every answer is welcome. Thanks)

(EDIT)
For those one who needs the client code, so here it is:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ClientConnnection{
    // There is a method that i don't make yet
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            Socket socketToServer = new Socket("localhost",8010);
            ObjectOutputStream outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socketToServer.getOutputStream());
            outStream.writeObject(new Message("Hello :D"));
            outStream.writeObject(new Message("How r u?"));
            outStream.writeObject(new Message("Other message"));
            outStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of this line `while(!msg.equals("FINISH CONNECTION"));` ?

Comment: Relating to the question's title: as far as I know, reading from the connection's `InputStream` is a blocking operation, which means that when there is nothing sent by the client, then the `InputStream` will block waiting until there is. It will not throw any exception if/while the connection is valid. Can you show the client's code?

Comment: the purpose of this line ```while(!msg.equals("FINISH CONNECTION"));``` is to stop reading from the stream when the stream gets the string "FINISH CONNECTION"

Comment: So why aren't you sending it? Instead you are allowing your client to exit without even closing the socket. This will cause either an `IOException: connection reset` or an `EOFException`, depending on your platform. I suggest you impplement your application protocol properly. It's your design. But you don't need the `FINISH CONNECTION` message. Just close the stream in the sender, and the receiver will incur an `EOFException`, which you should catch separately, and probably not log..

Comment: I use the `!msg.equals("FINISH CONNECTION"` in the code, but it will be replaced by another sentence like a boolean var (for example: `private boolean connectionFinished;` would be its statement) that it'll change when the server or the client wants to finish the connection, the server or the client will send a object that is going to do it. (I hope this is the clarification of the `FINISH CONNECTION`)

Comment: But (1) you aren't sending it, or even closing the socket properly, and (2) you don't need it. I('ve already stated all this. Fix your code and re-test.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I fixed the code, i put the `close()` method after the iteration and finally i used the "FINISH CONNECTION" to stop the connection

Comment: Which you stll don't need. Sigh.